# Scan through all the sort keys of a particular hash in DynamoDB

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

For example, I have a table with userID as hash key. The same table contains commentID as range key. I want to find all entries related to a specific userID. Using java SDK, what is the most efficient way to retrieve all items that has a particular hash key.

**SOLUTION**

Here's how I did it:

```
QuerySpec spec = new QuerySpec()
                .withKeyConditionExpression("userID = :v_id")
                .withValueMap(new ValueMap()
                    .withString(":v_id", user.getId()));

ItemCollection<QueryOutcome> items = table.query(spec);

Iterator<Item> iterator = items.iterator();
Item item = null;
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
      item = iterator.next();
      System.out.println(item.toJSONPretty());
}
```

Comment: Just use query or getItem to get all the values of your hash key..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to "scan" a hash key in DynamoDB is called [Query](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryingJavaDocumentAPI.html).
Use this API either with the DynamoDBMapper or Document API to fetch all items for a specific hash.